# Where do I find Leah's journal?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I found Part 1 of Leah's journal in her room of the Slaughtered Calf Inn. Where do I find the remaining parts? And how many parts are there?

Comment: those journals are giving me trouble >.< Found one in open map in a box. I just can't be sure if was leah's

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Leah has 16 journals.** They respawn in the same places in the first three acts, new journals taking the previous journal's place (so get them while you can). You can return to previous chapters if need be.

#### Act 1's Tristram journals 1-7 are on a table in Leah's Room, a room in the back of the Inn.

- **Part 1**: during The Fallen Star (Quest 1)
- **Part 2**: during The Legacy of Cain (before entering the Cathedral—Quest 2)
- **Part 3**: during A Shattered Crown (Quest 3)
- **Part 4**: during Sword of the Stranger (Quest 5)
- **Part 5**: during The Broken Blade (Quest 6)
- **Part 6**: during The Doom in Wortham (Quest 7)
- **Part 7**: during Trailing the Coven (Quest 8)
  [image: Act 1] [image: Act 1]

#### Act 2's Caldeum journals 1-5 (8-12 in the old scheme) are on a table in the east of in the town.

- **Part 1**: during the *last part* of Shadows in the Desert (Quest 1)
- **Part 2**: during City of Blood (Quest 3)
- **Part 3**: during Betrayer of the Horadrim (Quest 6)
- **Part 4**: during The Black Soulstone (Quest 8)
- **Part 5**: during The Scouring of Caldeum (Quest 9)
  [image: Act 2] [image: Act 2]

#### Act 3's Keep journals 1-4 (13-16 in the old scheme) are in the southeast room of the Armory (the room in the town's southeast corner with Adria/Leah)

- **Part 1**: during The Siege of Bastion's Keep (Quest 1)
- **Part 2**: during Turning the Tide (Quest 2)
- **Part 3**: during the middle part of The Breached Keep (Find the Breach - Quest 3)
- **Part 4**: during Heart of Sin (Quest 7)
  [image: Act 3] [image: Act 3]

**There are many lore books.** You can check your book collection progress from the achievement list (press <kbd>Y</kbd>). Leah's journals are listed under `Campaign > Acts 1-3` in the "People lore book" achievement.
[image: Achievement list]

Comment: I could not find Leah's Caldeum journal Part 5 in Quest 9; I had to activate Quest 10 to get it.

Answer (score 11):

There are 16 parts of Leah's Journal. They are found in the same location in each of the town hubs in Acts I-III. **The specific parts are available *immediately* from the start of the first listed quest (it must have been started and listed as your objective) until the end of the last listed quest (no longer listed as your objective)** in the list to follow.

Parts 1-7 are found in the back room of the tavern in New Tristram in Act I:

- Part 1. During *The Fallen Star*
- Part 2. During *The Legacy of Kain*
- Part 3. During *A Shattered Crown* & *Reign of the Black King*
- Part 4. During *Sword of the Stranger*
- Part 5. During *The Broken Blade*
- Part 6. During *The Doom in Wortham*
- Part 7. During *Trailing the Coven* until the end of Act I

Parts 8-12 are found on a table to the south-east of the Hidden Camp in Caldeum in Act II:

- Part 8. During *Shadows in the Desert*
- Part 9. During *The Road to Alcarnus (from Find the Khasim Outpost)* & *City of Blood*
- Part 10. During *Unexpected Allies* & *Betrayer of the Horadrim*
- Part 11. During *Blood and Sand* & *The Black Soulstone*
- Part 12. During *The Scouring of Caldeum* until the end of Act II.

Parts 13-16 are found on a table to the south-east of The Armory in Bastion's Keep in Act III:

- Part 13. Before and during *The Siege of Bastion's Keep*
- Part 14. During *Turning The Tide*
- Part 15. During *The Breached Keep (from Find the Breach in the Keep Depths)*
- Part 16. During *Tremors in the Stone* until the end of Act III

You can check which ones you've seen across all your characters by checking the People Lore achievements A Quick Study (Campaign Act I), Judge of Character (Campaign Act II) and Primary Sources (Campaign Act III). **Each character records lore separately so the only ways to know if a specific lore has been read by a given character (for the XP bonus if not for being thorough) is to check for it in the lore screen or to try reading the specific lore**.

Comment: Does she have some in Act 2? I could swear I've read some there, too.

Comment: Yes. Act 3 too. I am adding the rest as I confirm when exactly they are available.

Comment: I appreciate your work on this and upvoted your answer, but it looks like Sean beat you to a complete list so I'm awarding him the bounty.

Comment: @Sterno No worries. His answer was a few hours after mine while I was still compiling and testing information as well as doing other things. I sort of lost motivation once I saw his, but I'll still complete this one as there are some points that Sean has incorrect/incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Leah's journal is tied to how far you are along Act 1.

Each time you complete a major quest, go back to her room to find another page of her journal.

Cain has journals within his house in New Tristram as well.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Leah's Keep Journal 2 is not during the first part of The Breached Keep, it's actually during the second quest Turning the Tide.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on that answer a bit more.